# Find all indices where value of array changes

Tags: python, array

I try to solve the following problem using Python:
Given a 1-dimensional numeric array `arr`, find all indices where the value of `arr` changes. Return for each pair `(a, b)` (where `a != b`) an iterator of the indices `i` where `arr[i] == a` and `arr[i+1] == b`.

Example:
If the input array was `[1,1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1]`, then the function should return the following pairs and iterators:

```
(1, 5): [6],
(5, 1): [17],
(1, 4): [23],
(4, 1): [32]
```

If the input is `[1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,1,4,4,4]`, then the function should return:

```
(1, 4): [4, 10, 20],
(4, 1): [8],
(4, 3): [16],
(3, 1): [19]
```

In my current implementation, for each pair a `list` is returned, but it may be any iterator. All lists are contained in a dictionary (a `defaultdict`, to be precise), but they may be returned in any style.

This is my current implementation:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def find_changepoints(arr):
    changepoints = defaultdict(list)
    current_value = arr[0]
    for (index, value) in enumerate(arr):
        if value != current_value:
            changepoints[ (current_value, value) ].append(index)
            current_value = value
    
    return changepoints
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor feedback about your existing solution: add PEP484 type hints; `enumerate(arr[1:])` instead of over the whole array; no need to enclose your tuple index in parens; add unit tests.

If this is homework, a programming challenge or whatever and exists in a vacuum, you've basically met the brief. If this is for a specific application and you can replace the dictionary representation with something more efficient, then that will benefit you. For example, the following implementation has a dictionary wrapper that mimics yours around a vectorised function. If you have an application that is able to use the vectorised function directly, it will be faster for large arrays.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from numbers import Real
from typing import Sequence

import numpy as np


def changed_where_numpy(in_seq: np.ndarray) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # old values
    np.ndarray,  # new values
    np.ndarray,  # new indices
]:
    old_idx, = np.diff(in_seq).nonzero()
    new_idx = old_idx + 1
    return in_seq[old_idx], in_seq[new_idx], new_idx


def changed_where(in_seq: Sequence[Real]) -> dict[
    tuple[Real, Real],  # old and new value
    list[int],          # new value indices
]:
    old_vals, new_vals, new_idx = changed_where_numpy(np.array(in_seq))
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for old_val, new_val, new_idx in zip(old_vals, new_vals, new_idx):
        result[old_val, new_val].append(new_idx)
    return result


def test():
    in_seq = (
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    )
    expected = {
        (1, 5): [6],
        (5, 1): [17],
        (1, 4): [23],
        (4, 1): [32],
    }
    actual = changed_where(in_seq)
    assert expected == actual

    in_seq = (
        1, 1, 1, 1,
        4, 4, 4, 4,
        1, 1,
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
        3, 3, 3,
        1,
        4, 4, 4,
    )
    expected = {
        (1, 4): [4, 10, 20],
        (4, 1): [8],
        (4, 3): [16],
        (3, 1): [19]
    }
    actual = changed_where(in_seq)
    assert expected == actual


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Return for each pair (a, b) (where a != b) an iterator of the indices i where arr[i] == a and arr[i+1] == b.

You failed the task, since your function is not returning an *iterator of indices*. Also, if you read your task carefully, your indices are off by 1.

```py
from itertools import islice
from typing import Iterator


def changes(lst: list) -> Iterator[int]:
    for index, (current, next) in enumerate(zip(lst, islice(lst, 1, None))):
        if current != next:
            yield index
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my misconception. I mixed up the words _iterable_ and _iterator_ when I formulated the task. I will not edit my initial question as to not make your answer invalid.

Comment: I see. Given your question, I assumed that the task was given to you by a third party as cited by you.

Comment: This solution seems to return a single iterator of all changes in the whole input list, whilst the task is (if I get it correctly) to return a separate iterator for each distinct pair of values at the constant runs' boundaries.